# Get Extension cannot find repeat index in Workflow item

Tags: workflow, 2011-sp1, dwt

I'm in the process of implementing Workflow, but am running into trouble with a particular template.  Here's the test case:

> 1. Created new image component – chimp2 – Save & Close
> 2. Goto content Component
> 3. Added chimp2 image to Component - Save & Close
> 4. Go to workflow – “Finish activity” on Component. Component is published to preview.

Step 4 triggers a Component publish into a preview environment in Workflow using `WorkItem.Publish("tcm:1-2-3", True, True, True)`, which as I understand it should publish the Workflow version of the Component.

However, when publishing against this DWT:

```
<img src="@@image@@" alt="@@Get('Fields.paragraphs[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].image.Metadata.description')@@" class="content-image @@image_alignment@@" />
```

I'm getting a rendering error from Get, which reads:

> Expression 'Get("Fields.paragraphs[2].image.Metadata.description")' had error 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

But in the workflow version of the Component, the index exists.

Interestingly, if I rewrite the code to use DGX's GetFromItem:

```
<img src="@@image@@" alt="@@GetFromItem("${image}", "Metadata.description")@@" />
```

Then everything is found OK.

Is there a known issue or workaround in the Get extension when used within Workflow?  I would prefer to update Workflow VB than troubleshoot 60 templates, given the choice!

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround for this, I believe you can include the following lines of code:

PublishInstructionData publishInstruction = new PublishInstructionData();
publishInstruction.ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData(); 
publishInstruction.RenderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData();

//Needed for publishing workflow revision/version:

publishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeWorkflow = true;

Then when you do your publish, pass the publishInstruction. I.e.:

PublishTransactionData[] publishTransactions = SessionAwareCoreServiceClient.Publish(itemsToPublishList.ToArray(), publishInstruction, targets, PublishPriority.Normal, null);

Comment: Yup, I would think this solves it. Basically the current publish instruction doesn't tell Tridion to "use workflow version", while GetItem gets the _latest_ version available to the current user (i.e., the one in workflow).